# On click of Send button in chatbox output is not visible on chatbox screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

My send button on chatbox is not working. I am using Javascript and Jquery. I tried the code separately it's working but when I combine the code with that of chatbox I am not getting a message on my chatbox screen. Also the minimize button is not working although I have commented it in the code. Apart from this there is a style file and a jquery file

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var arr = []; // List of users 

//function to minimize the chat
$(document).on('click','.msg_head',function(){
    var chatbox=$(this).parents().attr("rel");
    $('[rel="'+chatbox+'"].msg_wrap').slideToggle('slow');
    displayChatBox();
    return false;
});


 //function to close the chat
 $(document).on('click', '.close', function() { 
  var chatbox = $(this).parents().parents().attr("rel") ;
  $('[rel="'+chatbox+'"]').hide();
  arr.splice($.inArray(chatbox, arr), 1);
  displayChatBox();
  return false;
 });

 // function for send button//
function sendMessage(e) {
/*$("#send_messagessage").addClass("disabled");
    if(typeof e.type !== 'string' || (e.type == 'keyup' && e.keyCode != 13)) {
        //return $('#status').html('no call');
        return false;
    }
    $('#status').html('made call');*/
    var msg = document.getElementById("text_msg").value;; //retrieve msg from text

    if(msg.trim().length != 0){    
    var chatbox = $(this).parents().parents().parents().attr("rel") ;
    $('<div class="msg-right">'+msg+'</div>').insertBefore('[rel="'+chatbox+'"] .msg_push');
    $('.msg_body').scrollTop($('.msg_body')[0].scrollHeight);
    var product = output(msg);
    $('<div class="msg-left">'+product+'</div>').insertBefore('[rel="'+chatbox+'"] .msg_push');
    $('.msg_body').scrollTop($('.msg_body')[0].scrollHeight);
}

};

 $(document).on('click', '#sidebar-user-box', function() {

  var userID = $(this).attr("class");
  var username = $(this).children().text() ;

  if ($.inArray(userID, arr) != -1)
  {
      arr.splice($.inArray(userID, arr), 1);
     }

  arr.unshift(userID);
  chatPopup =  '<div class="msg_box" rel="'+ userID+'">'+
     '<div class="msg_head">'+username +
     '<div class="close">X</div> </div>'+
     '<div class="msg_wrap"> <div class="msg_body"> <div class="msg_push"></div> </div>'+
     '<div class="msg_footer"><input class="msg_input" placeholder="Enter Message..." type="text"><button id="send_message" type="submit" >Send</button>'+
     '</div></div></div>' ;     

     $("body").append(  chatPopup  );
  displayChatBox();
 });


 $(document).on('keypress', 'input' , function(e) {       
        if (e.keyCode == 13 ) {   
            var msg = $(this).val(); 
            $(this).val(""); 
   if(msg.trim().length != 0){    
   var chatbox = $(this).parents().parents().parents().attr("rel") ;
   $('<div class="msg-right">'+msg+'</div>').insertBefore('[rel="'+chatbox+'"] .msg_push');
   $('.msg_body').scrollTop($('.msg_body')[0].scrollHeight);
    var product = output(msg);
    $('<div class="msg-left">'+product+'</div>').insertBefore('[rel="'+chatbox+'"] .msg_push');
    $('.msg_body').scrollTop($('.msg_body')[0].scrollHeight);
}
   }        
    });

function output(input){
    try{
        var product = input + "=" + eval(input);
    } catch(e){
        var text = (input.toLowerCase()).replace(/[^\w\s\d]/gi, ""); //remove all chars except words, space and 
        text = text.replace(/ a /g, " ").replace(/i feel /g, "").replace(/whats/g, "what is").replace(/please /g, "").replace(/ please/g, "");
        if(compare(trigger, reply, text)){
            var product = compare(trigger, reply, text);
        } else {
            var product = alternative[Math.floor(Math.random()*alternative.length)];
        }
    }
    return product;
}

function compare(arr, array, string){
    var item;
    for(var x=0; x<arr.length; x++){
        for(var y=0; y<array.length; y++){
            if(arr[x][y] == string){
                items = array[x];
                item =  items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)];
            }
        }
    }
    return item;
}

function displayChatBox(){ 
     i = 0 ; // start position
  j = 260;  //next position

  $.each( arr, function( index, value ) {  
     if(index < 4){
          $('[rel="'+value+'"]').css("right",i);
    $('[rel="'+value+'"]').show();
       i = i+j;    
     }
     else{
    $('[rel="'+value+'"]').hide();
     }
        });  
 }  

});
```